# How to find a Word that is enclosed from Html Tags?

Tags: javascript, html, regex, spell-checking

I'm programming a spell checker in Javascript in combination with OpenOffice dictionary, and I have a serious problem.

I can find whole words using RegEx, but if the word looks like `prog<b>ram</b>ing`, I can find it if I remove all html tags with the `.text()` method from jQuery. But how can I replace this word and rebuild the original html structure?

[Spellchecker.com](http://www.spellchecker.net/spellcheck/) does it very smartly - the spell check recognizes even words like `prog<b>ram</b>ing` if they are misspelled!

Comment: With reference to using regex to process HTML, I'd suggest finding another way: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Answer (score 2):

```
/([\s>"'])prog(<[^>]+>)ram(<[^>]+>)ing([\s\.,:;"'<])/g
```

will match your example

So roughly the following regex will find all instances of the word, even those broken with html

```
 var regExp = new RegExp('([\s>"\'])' + word.split('').join('(<[^>]+>)') + '([\s\.,:;"\'<])',g);
```

God knows how that'll help you build a spellchecker though. I suspect the approach used in spellcheckers would be more like 'do a spellcheck assuming no html, and if there is html in a word then strip it out using something like the method below, and do a spellcheck as normal for the string you get:

```
String.prototype.stripHtml = function() {
  return this.replace(/(<[^>]+>)/, '');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use something to pull out any  HTML so that you are dealing with plaintext. I cannot speak for any tools like this in javascript but I'm sure they exists. If you can find something to 'scrub' the html out of your .text() you can run a search this way.

Try something like this: http://metacpan.org/pod/HTML::Scrubber